# Powershell script to check if a file exists on remote computer list

Tags: powershell

I'm new at Powershell, and I'm trying to write a script that checks if a file exists; if it does, it checks if a process is running.
I know there are much better ways to write this, but can anyone please give me an idea?
Here's what I have:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\SvcHosts\MaquinasEstag.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='SvcHosts Installed';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Windows\svchosts"}} 

   if(Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Windows\svchosts" eq "True")
   {
        Get-Content C:\temp\SvcHosts\MaquinasEstag.txt | `
        Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='SvcHosts Running';Expression={ Get-Process svchosts}} 
   }
```

The first part (check if the file exists, runs with no problem. But I have an exception when checking if the process is running:

```
Test-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'eq'.
At C:\temp\SvcHosts\TestPath Remote Computer.ps1:4 char:7
+    if(Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Windows\svchosts" eq "True")
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The equality comparison operator is `-eq`, not `eq`. The boolean value "true" in PowerShell is `$true`. And if you want to compare the result of `Test-Path` to something the way you do, you must run the cmdlet in a subexpression, otherwise `-eq "True"` would be treated as an additional option `eq` with the argument `"True"` to the cmdlet.

Change this:

```
if(Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Windows\svchosts" eq "True")
```

into this:

```
if ( (Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Windows\svchosts") -eq $true )
```

Or (better yet), since `Test-Path` already returns a boolean value, simply do this:

```
if (Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Windows\svchosts")
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, many thanks!!
However it's not showing for which machine the process is running.
My output is just a list from which machines has the file I'm looking for. However, if the file is there, I need to know also if a process is running. Is there a way to do that?
Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: `Select-Object` normally reads from a pipeline. If you use it inside a loop, you need to feed it via the `-InputObject` property: `Select-Object -InputObject $_ @{Name=...}`.